# Using strcat results in an empty string

Tags: c, string, strcat

I'm learning C and tried to make a little program to know how strings work. Using the `strcat` function with pointers to a `char` produces an empty string, even thought I initialize the first pointer dynamically with `malloc`. Why is this happening if both strings have been initialized?

Here's the code:

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    char *dest = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    char *src = "World";

    dest = "Hello";

    printf("%s", strcat(dest, src)); // <-- gives an empty string
}
```

Comment: `dest = "Hello";` throws away the allocated memory and replaces the pointer with a pointer to a string literal - and you cannot modify a string literal, so your `strcat` call invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, @UnholySheep. I read about that a little ago but didn't think its impacts 'til now. Thanks for helping this guy in his journey .

Answer (score 2):

You have changed what area of memory `dest` points to. (Remember, `dest` is a pointer, not an array or the memory itself.)

As a consequence you are now trying to write to read-only memory (where the `"Hello"` string is located in memory), which is causing failure.

An additional consequence is that the chunk of memory obtained by `malloc` was lost, as you now have no way to release it back to the memory manager. In software we call this a “leak”, as in *it leaks memory*.

To fix it, use `strcpy` to *copy* the `"Hello"` string to your allocated memory spot, which is both writable and, as you coded it, large enough to hold a 19-character string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main() 
{ 
   char *dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
   char *src = "World";

   // copy hello to dest[], replacing what was there before
   strcpy(dest, "Hello");  

   // append src[] to dest[], return dest, print it
   printf("%s", strcat(dest, src)); 

   // don't forget to clean up!
   free(dest);
}
```

Always remember to watch the size of your string arrays that they are large enough to accept everything you wish to append (concatenate) to them. In this example it is sufficient, but still very, very small.

You may also consider appending a space to separate your strings, and either printing a newline at the end of your input or flushing the output stream in order to guarantee immediate output.

Comment: huge thanks for your reply @Dúthomhas. I wan's pretty sure about the error until this beautiful community helped me. Best of luck to you wherever you are! 

Comment: Suggestion: Include the additional remark that the value of `dest` as provided by `malloc` is now lost. The memory associated with it cannot be freed, thus, this is a memory leak.

Comment: @Yun Thank you for your wisdom, great man .